# Finding an empty slot in an array of registers

Tags: verilog, cpu, computer-architecture

I'm working to implement an out of order processor in Verilog, and I'm trying to quickly find an empty slot in an array of reservation stations like so

```
reg [39:0]add_rStation[3:0];
```

Assume each station has a valid bit indicating whether it is full or not. By quickly I mean without big if else chain.
Does anyone know of way to do this *Mathmatically* (for lack of a better term)?

Comment: What is station? What do you mean *space* being *empty*? Each bit can be 0 or 1, both values are valid. There can not be "invalid" values in there. (Edit: I am wrong, there could be value X, but it may be invalid from implementation point of view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you're looking for is called a "priority encoder". It will take a set of bits and give you the number of the lowest-numbered bit that is asserted. If you invert your "valid" bits to create a set of "empty" bits for the *reservation stations* (a term that I first saw in conjunction with the IBM System 360 Model 91), the priority encoder will give you the number of the first available one.

The HDL source code for a priority encoder is indeed a large combinatorial `if-then-else` statement, but this is a common construct and the synthesis tools can map it efficiently onto the underlying hardware.

My first full-time job after college (early 1980s) was to design a new CPU for scientific applications, and I borrowed heavily from the 360/91 design. Unfortunately, my design never got built, but I still have a lot of my design notes, and every now and then I think about doing it in an FPGA.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just have to go with an if else chain. At least that's easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

A for statement with static bounds is synthesizable:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1)
  if (add_rStation[i][33])
  begin
    slot <= i ;
    empty <= 1 ;
  end
```

"slot" gives you the slot that has bit-33 set if "empty" got stuffed with a 1. As it is written the higher, later index (represented by i) has higher priority.

(Obviously, you need to add proper declarations and preparations to the variables as written.)